# How to: Rest endpoint returning empty object

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, json, endpoints

I'd like to implement a custom REST endpoint that can also return an empty object. However, in the case where it should return an empty object, the empty associative array returned by the callback is transformed to an empty array.

How can I force the endpoint to transform the array into an object like I can in `json_encode` by setting the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag?

```
function rest_cb() {
    return array();  // this will result in the REST response [] but {} is required
}

function on_rest_api_init() {
    register_rest_route('ns/v1', 'empty-object', 'rest_cb');
}
```

Comment: just return json? and check for string type

Comment: There is no built-in json data type so I can't return json "itself". I only could return encoded json which would end in a string as the type of the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: By casting the return value to an object, it is ensured that in case of an empty array, an empty object will be returned on REST request.

Enhancing on my initial example, this code would work:

```
function rest_cb() {
    return (object) array();
}
```